# Libcurl throwing error when downloading ERROR : unknown error

Tags: c, libcurl

I am trying to test libcurl for my project, but when I want to download a test file I get error:

```
ERROR : Unknown error
```

but no reason why it happens,
my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
 
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    CURL *curl;
    FILE *fp;
    char name[30] = {"Test"};
    char link[100] = {"ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip"};
    CURLcode error;
    int result;
    fp = fopen(name,"Wb");

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt;(curl, CURLOPT_URL, argv[1] );
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1L);

    curl_easy_perform(curl);
    result = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    
    if (result = CURLE_OK)
        printf("Sucessful download !");
    else
        printf("Could not download, ERROR : %s \n",curl_easy_strerror(error));
        printf("%s",error);

    fclose(fp);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

Comment: `if (result = CURLE_OK)` should be comparison, not assignment: `if (result == CURLE_OK)`

Comment: @EmanuelP You are right but no changes....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bunch of errors in the code.

- The argument to `fopen` should be a *lower case* "w".
- You declare both `error` and `result` but should use only one.
- There's a stray semicolon in the middle of this line: `curl_easy_setopt;(curl, CURLOPT_URL, argv[1] );`

Combined with what's already mentioned, this should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    if(argc < 2) {
       puts("URL not given");
       return 1;
    }

    CURL *curl;
    FILE *fp;
    char name[30] = {"Test"};
    char link[100] = {"ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip"};
    CURLcode result;
    fp = fopen(name,"w");

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, argv[1] );
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1L);

    result = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    
    if (result == CURLE_OK)
        printf("Sucessful download !");
    else
        printf("Could not download, ERROR : %s \n",curl_easy_strerror(result));

    fclose(fp);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    return 0;
}
```

Don't forget to pass the URL as an argument, since you're not actually using `link` and don't check `argc`. And I advise you to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: so now I am facing another error
`ERROR : HTTP response code said error`

Comment: @yazdanrezaie That means the server returned an error. I can't help you with that. Probably just an invalid URL or a redirection. If you don't set CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, you'll download the response from the server. Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Complete guess - but could it have something to do with your code calling `curl_easy_perform(curl);` two times instead of once?

This looks suspicious:

```
curl_easy_perform(curl);
result = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

Shouldn't it just be:

```
result = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

Also, shouldn't `link` have the http prefix on it?

```
char link[100] = {"http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip"};
```

Comment: I removed that but nothing happend and the http part too

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to your code indentation there are braces missing at least in your else path. That means that the last printf is being executed regardless of the result value...
Does it work as expected if you add the braces like this? Of course together with the other suggestions as stated by selbie and Emanuel P...

```
if (result == CURLE_OK) {
    printf("Sucessful download !");
} else {
    printf("Could not download, ERROR : %s \n",curl_easy_strerror(error));
    printf("%s",error);
}
```

Comment: No matter , the braces do nothing.